# Background image isn't changed in Chrome/Mozilla

Tags: jquery

I have some input fields that user should fill all of them in order to sign up. Therefore wrote some jQuery code which detects if user leaves a control blank, a red error image is shown in input field.

```
$("#Ad,#Soyad,#Eposta,#EpostaOnay,#Sifre,#SifreOnay").on("blur", function () {

            if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
                $(this).css({ background: "url(images/core/input_error2.png) no-repeat !important" });
            }

        });
        $('#Ad,#Soyad,#Eposta,#EpostaOnay,#Sifre,#SifreOnay').on("focus", function () { 

            $(this).css('background', 'url(images/core/input2.png) no-repeat !important');

        });
```

This code works well in IE, but doesn't work with Chrome or Mozilla FF. I put some breakpoints on Chrome. It can detect if any element is focused or focused-out.

Comment: not sure if this helps, but maybe use === operator instead of ==.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Any reason why your blur callback uses the object `css(properties)` format whereas the focus callback uses the single assignment `css(propertyName, value)` format? Maybe you can try changing the blur callback to use the single assignment format. If anything, for consistency.

Comment: Seems to work ok [here](http://jsbin.com/oliYOhO/1/edit). Kolay gelsin.

Comment: @irot, i changed focus callback as you told but nothing changed. but i noticed something that if i put an "alert" function inside "focus" function, the alert pops-up continuously.

Comment: What do you see if you alert `$(this).val().trim().length` in your blur callback?